# React Three Fiber OBJLoader conflicts witth @types/three

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-typescript, react-three-fiber

I am following the official React Three Fiber Docs here. I am trying to load .obj files into my scene, using this article: [react-three-fiber docs: loading obj models](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/loading-models#loading-obj-models)
The trouble starts here:

> **Part 1: import of OBJLoader**

**Best case, I think this issue can be solved here.**

I'd be more than happy to find and solve the error here because it only gets uglier later on. Anyways, I can't seem to get the following line to work. Mind you, this is literally copy-pasted from the official docs:

```
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
```

This line is marked red in VSC, and when I hover over it, I get these pieces of information:

```
'OBJLoader' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Could not find a declaration file for module 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'. 'F:/Documents/myproject/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/three` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';`
```

Trying to host the project with `npm run`, from this point on, breaks with the following errors:

```
Failed to compile.
F:/Documents/myproject/src/components/editor/Editor.tsx
Type error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'. 'F:/Documents/myproject/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/three` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';`  TS7016
```

> **Part 2: Installing @types/three**

The error messages told me to `npm i --save-dev @types/three`, so I did. This resolves the import error, **but** it opens up a whole 'nother can of worms:

I have a BoxComponent that I am adding to my scene (I am only just starting out with react three fiber and I wanted to start with simple boxes before working my way to custom imported .obj files). It's based on [another page from the official React Three Fiber Docs](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction), rudimentally tweaked to fit my project's needs. Here's its basic conent:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { BoxGeometryProps, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";

export interface BoxProps {
  position: Array<number>;
  optinalParam?: string;
}

const Box = (props: BoxProps) => {
  const ref = useRef(Object);
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(false);
  const [clicked, click] = useState(false);

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    let refCurrent: BoxGeometryProps | undefined = ref.current; // [ERROR #1]
    if (refCurrent !== undefined) {
      refCurrent.rotation.z += 0.005; // [ERROR #2]
      refCurrent.rotation.x -= 0.005; // [ERROR #2]
    }
  });

  return (
    <mesh
      position={props.position} // [ERROR #3]
      ref={ref}
      scale={clicked ? 2.0 : 1}
      onClick={(event) => click(!clicked)}
      onPointerOver={(event) => hover(true)}
      onPointerOut={(event) => hover(false)}
    >
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? "lightgreen" : "lime"} />
    </mesh>
  );
};

export default function MyBox(props: BoxProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Box position={props.position} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[ERROR #1]:

```
Value of type 'ObjectConstructor' has no properties in common with type 'ExtendedColors<Overwrite<Partial<BoxGeometry>, NodeProps<BoxGeometry, typeof BoxGeometry>>>'. Did you mean to call it?ts(2560)
BoxComponent.tsx(21, 56): Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?
```

[ERROR #2]:

```
Property 'rotation' does not exist on type 'ExtendedColors<Overwrite<Partial<BoxGeometry>, NodeProps<BoxGeometry, typeof BoxGeometry>>>'.ts(2339)
```

[ERROR #3]:

```
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'Vector3 | undefined'.
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[x: number, y: number, z: number]'.
Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
three-types.d.ts(35, 5): The expected type comes from property 'position' which is declared here on type 'MeshProps'
```

Looking at it just now, I have a feeling that the solution could be found with this last line `three-types.d.ts(35, 5): The expected type...` But, in all honesty, I don't know how @types packages work at all and, as mentioned before, I think this could be resolved in Part 1 and I would be mega happy about that.

I don't post often but I am very frustrated here. I am following the official docs, with a few minor expansions and tweaks, and yet my project is suddenly completely busted, when I install one more little package via npm.
Very much looking forward for help, and a big, big thank you in advance.

P.S., here's my `package.json`:

```css
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-three/drei": "^8.16.4",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^7.0.26",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.17",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.44",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "three": "^0.137.5",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "zustand": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/three": "^0.140.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get rid of all the errors. Can't say I fully understand it but it's definitely related to `useRef()` and its secret magic. Providing it with a "strong enough" type in my `BoxComponent` resolved the issues: like such:

BEFORE:

`const meshRef = useRef<BoxGeometryProps>(null);`

AFTER:

`const mesh = useRef<Mesh>(null);`

With Mesh imported straight from `three`. I can't shake the feeling that this is gonna give me trouble again soon, since I feel like I should be use as much stuff as possibly from `react-three-fiber`, rather than `three`. But, for now, this question can be marked as solved.